# How can I study the integral inequality $f(t)\leq (\log{a})\int_s^t f(r)dr+c(\log{a})(t-s)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be a continuous function. Also, let $a,c>1$ two constants.

In my studies it was proved the following inequality:

$$f(t)\leq (\log{a})\int_s^t f(r)dr+c(\log{a})(t-s)$$

with $0\leq s<t$.

After that the author has asserted that this implies, after integrating, the following inequality:

$$f(t)\leq c(a^{t-s}-1)$$

But I wasn't able to prove that. I've tried a lot of things, but none of them give me such inequality.

My best attempt so far:

note that $$f(t)-\log{a}\int_s^tf(r)dr\leq c\log{a} (t-s)$$

thus

$$a^{-t+s}f(t)-a^{-t+s}\log{a}\int_s^tf(r)dr\leq a^{-t+s}c\log{a^{t-s}}$$

but this just means that

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(a^{-t+s}\int_s^tf(r)dr\right)\leq a^{-t+s}c\log{a^{t-s}}$$

I'm here to ask you some hints. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found out a way to get what I wanted. I posted it as a answer to this question.

Comment: Can you share the source for this?

Comment: @CameronWilliams It is the book Morse Theoretic Aspects of p-Laplacian Type Operators, Lemma 3.7 page 49, inequality (3.7)

Comment: I see $\dfrac{f(t)}{\log(a)} \leq F(t)-F(s)+c(t-s)$ or $\dfrac{f(t)}{\log(a^{t-s})}-c\leq \dfrac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s} $ where the RHS looks like $F'=f.$

Comment: @MariusS.L. Yeah, I see that also. But I don't know if it helps...

Comment: @Jacaré I ran into circular conclusions when I tried to prove it. Question: is $f(t):=e^{t-s}-1$ with $a=e $ and $c=2$ a counterexample? (I only scribbled it on the back of an envelope so I'm not 100% certain.)

Comment: @MariusS.L. I think it's not a counter example, because it satisfies trivially the inequality $e^{t-s}-1<2(e^{t-s}-1)$

Comment: @Jacaré oops! Too late here. I placed it between $f(t)$ and the integral expression instead of to the left of it. My idea for the proof was by contradiction. Say $f(t_0)>c(a^{t_0-s}-1)=:g(t_0)$ for some $t_0 \in (s,t)$ and $s$ sufficiently close to $t_0$ so that we can use differentiation and integration in a neighborhood and still be less than $f(t_0).$ Also $g(t)=c(a^{t-s}-1)$ can be expressed in terms of $g'(t).$ $a=e$ can be assumed w.l.o.g. to make calculations easier. But as mentioned, I ran into circular conclusions, so I started to think about a counterexample.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Hmm. I see. This is a possible way to handle that. But I think it can be very hard to go in that way... But I may be wrong.

Comment: We get from the mean value theorem of integration
$$
f(t)\leq (\log a)\int_s^t f(r)dr + c(\log a)(t-s)=f(\xi)(t-s)+c(\log a)(t-s)=\mathcal{O}(t-s)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suffice to use [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) here.

> It says that if $\beta$ and $u$ are continuous and the negative part of $\alpha$ is integrable with $\beta(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$ and
>
> $$u(t)\leq\alpha(t)+\int_s^t\beta(r)u(r)dr$$
>
> then
>
> $$u(t)\leq\alpha(t)+\int_s^t\alpha(r)\beta(r)\exp\left(\int_r^t\beta(h)dh\right)dr$$

Well, we can apply such inequality to our case where

$$u(t)=f(t)$$

$$\alpha(t)=c(\log{a})(t-s)$$

$$\beta(t)=\log{a}$$

Then note that $$\int_s^t\alpha(r)\beta(r)\exp\left(\int_r^t\beta(h)dh\right)dr=c(\log{a})^2\int_s^ta^{t-r}(r-s)dr$$

Integrating by parts we have

$$\int_s^ta^{t-r}(r-s)dr=-\dfrac{t-s}{\log{a}}-\dfrac{1}{(\log{a})^2}+\dfrac{a^{t-s}}{(\log{a})^2}$$

Therefore
$$c(\log{a})^2\int_s^ta^{t-r}(r-s)dr=-c(\log{a})(t-s)-c+ca^{t-s}$$

Finally, adding $\alpha(t)=c(\log{a})(t-s)$ we have

$$\alpha(t)+\int_s^t\alpha(r)\beta(r)\exp\left(\int_r^t\beta(h)dh\right)dr=c(a^{t-s}-1)$$

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

We get from the mean value theorem of integration
$$
f(t)\leq (\log a)\int_s^t f(r)dr + c(\log a)(t-s)=(\log a)f(\xi)(t-s)+c(\log a)(t-s)=\mathcal{O}(t-s)
$$
Now if $f(t)$ is bounded by a linear function from above, then it is also bounded by $c_0(a^{t-s}-1)$ with possibly another constant $c_0=(\log a)(f(\xi)+c).$

Comment: @SineoftheTime Yes, thank you. I corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I really need the inequality $\leq c(a^{t-s}-1)$. And I think your assumption about the boundness of $f$ by a linear function is too restrictive.